# Включение и выключение команды

Tags: python, discord, бот

Вот у меня есть код для автомодерации плохих слов

```py
#Фильтр плохих слов
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: return # если сообщение от бота - игнорируем
    banwords = ["хуй", "блядина", "пизда", "пидр", "пидор", "пидар", "пидорас", "пидарас", "гандон", "сука", "даун", "дибил", "сучка", "ебать", "еблан", "ахуеть", "ебать", "нихуя", "пиздец", "блядь", "блять", "член", "залупа"]
    for word in banwords:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            try:
                await message.delete()
            except:
                pass
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, мат запрещен!')
            break
```

И я хочу сделать так, чтобы эту автомодерацию можно было включить либо выключить командой, по типу **>auto_on** и после этого автомодерация будет работать

Comment: Здравствуйте! Сейчас я тестирую на своём боте мой вариант. В течении.. скажем минут 10 вы получите ответ с объяснениями! Приятного вам вечера)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P.S: Это было сложно, но я сделал это.

**Здравствуйте**, уважаемый halflite. Сейчас я вам попытаюсь **максимально помочь**, а так-же разъяснить, что надо сделать, что добавить, а что убрать.

### Создаем главное условие вашей идеи.

Где угодно в коде добавляем такую вещь как: `auto_moderation_on = 'true'`. Это будет отвечать за нашу систему модерирования сообщений. Лично я поставил это перед кодом нашего ивента и команды.

### Начинаем кодить `@bot.event`

В начале кода добавляем три вот таких строчки:

```py
 if message.content.startswith('вашпрефиксздесь'): 
    await client.process_commands(message)`
 else:
```

Следующим действием я переместил список наших плохих слов перед проверкой на auto_moderation_on является `True`, или `False`. Вот как это выглядит:

```py
    banwords = ["тут очень плохие слова!"]
    if banwordson == 'true':
```

Код, который у вас там, т.е. где бот пытается удалить сообщение оставляем таким-же, как и у нас было. Теперь в конце мы добавляем две строчки:

```py
    elif banwordson == 'false':
        pass
```

Вот как будет выглядить наш `@bot.event`:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('lv.'): await client.process_commands(message)
 else:
    banwords = ["хуй", "блядина", "пизда", "пидр", "пидор", "пидар", "пидорас", "пидарас", "гандон", "сука", "даун", "дибил", "сучка", "ебать", "еблан", "ахуеть", "ебать", "нихуя", "пиздец", "блядь", "блять", "член", "залупа"]
    if banwordson == 'true':
        if message.author == bot.user: return
        for word in banwords:
            if word in message.content.lower():
                try:
                    await message.delete()
                except:
                    pass
                await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, мат запрещен!')
                break
    elif banwordson == 'false':
        pass
```

### Создаем команду включения-и-выключения автоматической модерации сообщений.

Создаем нашу основу, впринципе это ничего обычного.

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['automoder', 'moder', 'mat'])
@commands.has_role("ВнесиЗдесьРолиКоторыеМогутИспользоватьКоманды")
async def automoderation(ctx):
```

Далее  мы добавляем такую вещь, как `global auto_moderation_on`.
И теперь мы проверяем, если auto_moderation_on = True, то мы выключаем, а если наоборот, ну вы поняли.

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['automoder', 'moder', 'mat'])
@commands.has_role("ВнесиЗдесьРолиКоторыеМогутИспользоватьКоманды")
async def automoderation(ctx):
 global banwordson
 if banwordson == 'true':
     await ctx.reply('Здравствуйте, уважаемый администратор! Выключаю автоматическую модерацию...')
     banwordson = 'false' 
 else:
     await ctx.reply('Здравствуйте, уважаемый администратор! ~~Выключаю~~ Включаю автоматическую модерацию...')
     banwordson = 'true'
```

### Что у нас получается в итоге?

Теперь, вы можете включать и выключать автоматическую модерацию мата!

## Полный код

```py
banwordson = 'true'

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('ваш префикс тут'): await client.process_commands(message)
 else:
    banwords = ["хуй", "блядина", "пизда", "пидр", "пидор", "пидар", "пидорас", "пидарас", "гандон", "сука", "даун", "дибил", "сучка", "ебать", "еблан", "ахуеть", "ебать", "нихуя", "пиздец", "блядь", "блять", "член", "залупа"]
    if banwordson == 'true':
        if message.author == bot.user: return
        for word in banwords:
            if word in message.content.lower():
                try:
                    await message.delete()
                except:
                    pass
                await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, мат запрещен!')
                break
    elif banwordson == 'false':
        pass

@bot.command()
async def automoderation(ctx):
 global banwordson
 if banwordson == 'true':
     await ctx.reply('Здравствуйте, уважаемый администратор! Выключаю автоматическую модерацию...')
     banwordson = 'false' 
 else:
     await ctx.reply('Здравствуйте, уважаемый администратор! ~~Выключаю~~ Включаю автоматическую модерацию...')
     banwordson = 'true'
```

Спасибо за то, что дочитали до этого момента. Удачного вам вечера)

### Небольшое изменение

Можно было изменить код @bot.event'а как то так:

```py
if banwordson == 'true':
    if message.author != bot.user:
        #код
```

Comment: В `banwordson` можно записывать значения `True` или `False`, вместо `'true'` и `'false'`. Тогда можно будет упростить проверки и вместо `if banwordson == 'true'` сделать просто `if banwordson` (и вместо `if banwordson == 'false'` - `if not banwordson`). А вообще, хорошая реализация :)

Comment: Вов спасибо вам большое! Видимо вы не плохо розбираетесь в этом, удачи вам!

Comment: Ответ @denisnumb: Хм.. А в какой-то степени я с вами согласен. Можно и так, сейчас немного отредактирую.

Comment: Ответ @halflite : Всегда пожалуйста! И вам :)